# How can I keep both the first and last names in l?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I save bill gates and mark zuckerberg in lis?

When I write to the sedond, the first is lost

```
class student:
    def __init__(self,name,surname):
        self.name=name
        self.surname=surname
    def studen(self):
        lis=[]
        lis.extend([self.name,self.surname])
        return lis

a=student("Bill","gates")
a=student("Mark","zuckerberg")
print(a.studen())
```

**result:**

```
['Mark', 'zuckerberg']
```

**i want:**

```
['Mark', 'zuckerberg', 'bill', 'gates']
```

Comment: It looks like you want `student` to represent a single student with properties `name` and `surname`. But you also want a list, this is a poor design. You should have a separate student list that holds `student` instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need a `class Student`, and a `class Students` to represent a collection of `Student`:

Maybe something like this:

```
class Student:

    def __init__(self, name, surname):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}, {self.surname}'

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)


class Students:

    def __init__(self, seq):
        self._students = seq[:]

    def append(self, student):
        self._students.append(student)

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(str(student) for student in self._students)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    bill = Student("Bill", "Gates")
    mark = Student("Mark", "Zuckerberg")
    students = Students([mark, bill])
    print(students)
```

#### output:

```
Mark, Zuckerberg
Bill, Gates
```

You could also subclass `list`, or some base class from the `collections` module; More simply, you also could use a plain python list to hold your instances of `Student`:

```
class Student:

    def __init__(self, name, surname):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} {self.surname}'

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    bill = Student("Bill", "Gates")
    mark = Student("Mark", "Zuckerberg")
    students = [mark, bill]
    print(students)
```

#### output:

```
[Mark Zuckerberg, Bill Gates]
```

Comment: Can not happen in one instance? Only in a, or only in b? –

Comment: No idea what you mean; can you please be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Make `lis` an instance attribute. The way you do overrides instance `a`, so the previous value is lost.

You can do:

```
class student:
    def __init__(self,name,surname):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.lis = [self.name, self.surname]
    def studen(self):
        return self.lis

a = student("Bill", "gates")
b = student("Mark", "zuckerberg")
print(a.studen() + b.studen())
# ['Bill', 'gates', 'Mark', 'zuckerberg']
```

Comment: Can not happen in one instance? Only in a, or only in b?

Comment: @koki, I have explained why using single instance does not work in my answer.